# If I flag a question as low quality, will I lose my vote to close?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I have a few questions. However, one stands to probably fall under a "feature request"; consult the side note.

The [Flag posts page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) area is unclear to me.

I also read through the [Cast close and reopen votes page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Under "Alternatives to closing" where it states:

*If you don't have enough reputation to cast close votes, or have used up your close votes for the day, there are alternatives:*

- *If the question is a duplicate, post a comment with a link to the original.*
- *If the question has serious problems (e.g. it is spam or offensive), flag it instead.*

**Here are my questions:**

- **Q1:** I'm wondering why the flag for "low quality" is listed under the "flag" option. That to me means ***"raising a RED flag"***, in being sort of a bad thing. Say compared to flagging as **spam**, or **rude/abusive**, or to a **moderator** seem rather harsh. The flagging as a low-quality option should probably not be made available for members who have enough reputation points as opposed to members who can only flag as such because of them meeting the amount of rep required.

*Side note:* The latter for the above may fall under a feature request.

- **Q2:** If I **"flag"** a question as "very low quality" because it lacks information/code, will I lose my **vote to "close"** if they do not update their question in order to be clearer?

For instance; as "unclear" (or any other), or "Flagging > Closing > Off-topic because > Any of the listed options.

I ask this because I have gone through the [Flag posts page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) under the [Privileges page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and I did not find any information related to this.

And also because if I asked for clarification for them to update the question and I already "Flagged as very low-quality" where they failed to do so. This within the time frame allowed before the flag for "low quality" option disappears/is no longer available.

I haven't found a related question on meta that explicitly states "losing" a vote to "close" thereafter. Unless, I haven't looked long enough and that there is indeed a duplicate question of my question.

If there is one, then by all means close my question as per an already asked question of the same.

However, if the answer to my question is *"Yes, you lose my vote to close...",* then had I known that there stood to be a (possible) duplicate, because I/we now know what we're dealing with exactly, then the question may continue to remain in its present (unclear) state, and I'd of lost my shot in closing the question right away with a duplicate and would not have flagged it to begin with, and possibly no answers given which solved the question where a duplicate would have solved the question.

If my question needs to be improved and/or clarified, let me know in comments, and I will adjust it respectively.

Comment: You know you could trivially have tried this, right? No, flagging and voting to close are separate actions. You won't lose the ability to vote to close when you flag. That said, VLQ should only be used for posts that are so garbled as to no longer make any sense. Don't use the option when closing would do.

Comment: I will be totally honest with you *(as I am always)* @MartijnPieters is that yes; I could have and was going to do that, yet thought I would not have been able to close it as a duplicate; that was part of my question also. Now, do you feel that I should delete my question here, or would you like to submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Edit: Because you did answer my question, well part of it.

Comment: ...the part about the latter in my first question about the feature request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Btw, [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43431333/1415724) for the basis of my question. Where 2 comments were placed asking for code but we ignored. Look at the timestamps also and in regards to the OP's response/answer. There was a 30 minute window of pure silence on their part I could have closed that with one I thought would be the right one.

Comment: Just vote to close that post *early*. Don't wait, it can always be re-opened if the OP actually came back and posted code. See [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263). That post does not qualify for the VLQ flag, see [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265573)